# Binding Property<Predicate<MyObject>> to ListView (with SelectionMode.MULTIPLE)

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding

I'm attempting to bind between a `ListView` where more than one item can be selected and a `ObjectProperty`. When an item is selected, I want to filter a `TableView` column accordingly:

[image]

With the two lower filters (Components, Details), I do the binding like this:

```
ObjectProperty<Predicate<Log>> detailsSearchFilter = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
TextField detailsSearchField = new TextField();
detailsSearchField.setPromptText("e.g. finished initializing");
detailsSearchFilter.bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() ->

                    log -> log.getDetails().toLowerCase().contains(detailsSearchField.getText().toLowerCase()),
            detailsSearchField.textProperty()
    ));
```

Then later adding the logical operator method `and()` in order to be able to combine all filters:

```
logFilteredList.predicateProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() ->

                    detailsSearchFilter.get().and(componentSearchFilter.get()).and(sourceFilter.get()),
            detailsSearchFilter, componentSearchFilter, sourceFilter
    ));
```

For the other two `ListView` filters, I was thinking to do something like this:

```
private final static String[] sources = new String[]{"ECS","IISNode","PrismWebServer"};
ListView<String> sourceList = new ListView<>();
ObservableList sourceItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList(sources);

sourceList.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
sourceList.getItems().addAll(sources);
ListView<String> selected = new ListView<>();

sourceList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        selected.setItems(sourceList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(selected.getItems().toArray()));
    });
```

So the `selected` list now includes all values that are currently selected.
How do I bind the `sourceFilter` with all values of the `selected` list?

I was thinking of iterating through each value in the list and binding this way:

```
  sourceFilter.bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() ->

            log -> log.getSource().toLowerCase().contains(selected.getItems().get(i).toLowerCase()),
                sourceList.selectionModelProperty()

    ));
```

But it seems not very elegant and I'm not sure I'm using the `selectionModelProperty` in the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `selectionModelProperty` only triggers changes when the `selectionModel` is replaced which usually doesn't happen. The dependency should be to `sourceList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()`.

Furthermore the way I understand it you should query, if the `Log`'s `source` is among the selected items, not if the `source` string contains some part of the string at some position in the selected items list.

Also note that using a `ListView` just for storing the data should be avoided and for large lists it's much more efficient to do the `contains` checks on a `Set` instead of a `List`.

You could use code like this:

```
ObjectBinding<Predicate<Log>> binding = new ObjectBinding<Predicate<String>>() {
    private final Set<String> strings = new HashSet<>();

    {
        sourceList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends String> c) {
                boolean changed = false;

                // modify set on selection change
                while (c.next()) {
                    if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                        changed = true;
                        c.getRemoved().stream().map(String::toLowerCase).forEach(strings::remove);
                    }
                    if (c.wasAdded()) {
                        changed = true;
                        c.getAddedSubList().stream().map(String::toLowerCase).forEach(strings::add);
                    }
                }

                if (changed) {
                    invalidate();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Predicate<Log> computeValue() {
        return log -> strings.contains(log.getSource().toLowerCase());
    }

};
sourceFilter.bind(binding);
```